# Having problems matching whitespace whith MySql REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to match all phones in a database which don't match with the format of this example '(11) 1234-5678'.

I'm having troubles defining a regexp because of the whitespace, I have done this tests:

```
SELECT '(11) 1234-5678' REGEXP "\([0-9]{2}\)" -> 1
SELECT '(11) 1234-5678' REGEXP "\([0-9]{2}\).*" -> 1
SELECT '(11) 1234-5678' REGEXP "\([0-9]{2}\) " -> 0
SELECT '(11) 1234-5678' REGEXP "\([0-9]{2}\)[:blank:]" -> 0
SELECT '(11) 1234-5678' REGEXP "\([0-9]{2}\)[:space:]" -> 0
```

I have absolutely no idea of why I can't get mysql to match a whitespace.

**EDIT:**

I'm using mysql 5.5.24

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT '(11) 1234-5678' REGEXP "\\([0-9]{2}\\)[[:space:]]"
```

Comment: @hchinchilla You also need to escape `\` by `\\`, try again.